# Reply By Email to comment notifications

Tags: comments, email, notifications

This might be a somewhat broad question, but I'll try to keep it as specific as possible.

I need to implement two specific pieces of functionality on my WordPress site:

1. Allow users to subscribe to comments they make on pages, meaning that replies to those comments will be emailed to them.
2. Allow users to reply to said replies by replying to the email notification itself.

I've implemented the first requirement using the Subscribe to Comments Reloaded plugin, but I'm struggling to find a mature plugin which I can use to implement the second requirement. I'm ready to replace Subscribe to Comments Reloaded with a different plugin if said plugin can offer Reply By Email functionality.

Any suggestions on plugins I should look at?